# Genus of $y^3=(x^2+1)^2(x^3-1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to proving that the genus of the normalization of $C:y^3=(x^2+1)^2(x^3-1)$ is 4 by using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula on the projection map $\pi:C\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ which sends $[x:y:z]\mapsto[x:y]$. The map has degree 3 so we have $g(C)-1=\deg\pi(g(\mathbb{P}^1)-1)+\frac{b}{2}$.
Now, $\pi$ ramifies on $[1:\pm i:0],[1:-1:0],[1:\omega:0],[1:\bar{\omega}:0]$  ($\omega^3=-1$) with ramification index 2. Something must be wrong: the formula gives $g(C)=2+3(-1)+\frac{b}{2}=\frac{b}{2}-1$ but $[0:1]$ ramifies. You can see this considering the homogeneous polynomial $Z^4Y^3=(X^2+Z^2)^2(X^3-Z^3)$ and the preimage of $[0:1]$ given by $Z^4Y^3=(Z^2)^2(Z^3)$ which gives $Z^4(Y^3+Z^3)=0$ from which I get $[0:1:0],[0:{\omega}:1],[0:\bar{\omega}:1]$. They have positive ramification index so something must be wrong. Please help!

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow your work, but if I'm understanding correctly you are concerned that, after taking into account the ramification over $\infty$, the degree of the branch divisor is too high? I think what may be going on is that you are actually computing the arithmetic genus of the plane curve, and you will then need to account for what happens when you normalize (i.e. "unglue" the singular points)

Comment: Exactly. The problem is how to understand the ramification index of $\infty$

Comment: OK, so what I am saying is that you need to look at the partial derivatives and analyze the singularities; if the normalization has genus $4$, it's likely that the plane model has higher (arithmetic) genus, hence the reason you are getting larger total ramification than you expect. But I think you've already dealt with the ramification as needed.

Comment: I'm also a bit mystified by the $\frac{b}{2}$ term in your initial Riemann-Hurwitz computation. I've always written the ramification term as $\sum(e(P) - 1)$, where $e(P)$ is the index of ramification, so a point where two sheets come together contributes $1$, a point where three sheets come together contributes $2$, etc.

Comment: Yes, $b$ is exactly that sum. Maybe I am a bit confused, my curve is singular at $(\pm i,0)$. I have blown up at $(i,0)$ getting the equation $y=x^2(xy+2i)^2((x)^3-1)$. Do I have to consider this or do I have to blow the other singularity up? And them, I keep using RH formula with this new equation, right?

Comment: Yes, consider all singularities (careful: $(\pm i:0)\in\mathbb P^1$, so $C$ is singular *over* them, not at them). But I don't think you can apply RH to the blown-up equations; rather, use these blowups to understand the type of the singularities or rather their $\delta$-invariant, which is the decrease in the genus when you normalize the singularity. For example, the ordinary node and cusp both have $\delta=1$ since the normalization of a singular cubic is $\mathbb P^1$. If your normalization has genus $4$, this means that you want to show the genus of the plane model is $4+\sum\delta_i$.